# sql syntax error whith where and group by

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I wrote a command in sql server 2014 , the command fails  with the following error

### command

```
select * from View_FirstReport 
where Date Between '1392/03/20' and '1392/03/19', Insure_ID = '0', User_ID='2'                
Group by insure_id, InsureTitle, status
```

### error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2 Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: As said, the `,` is not a valid syntax in `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Given you have corrected the `WHERE` clause, I still don't think `SELECT *` is going to work well for you. Any reason why you are using GROUP BY?

Answer (score 1):

You should combine the parts of your query with `AND` and `OR`.

```
select 
  * 
from 
  View_FirstReport 
where
  Date Between '1392/03/20' and '1392/03/19' 
  AND Insure_ID = '0' 
  AND User_ID='2'   
Group by insure_id, InsureTitle, status
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `,` in your `WHERE` clause with `AND`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM View_FirstReport 
WHERE 
    Date Between '1392/03/20' AND '1392/03/19'
    AND Insure_ID = '0' AND User_ID='2'                
GROUB BY insure_id,InsureTitle,status
```

A detailed syntax definition of `WHERE` can for example be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hbceeb4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Use `AND` instead of `,`:

```
SELECT * FROM View_FirstReport
WHERE Date BETWEEN '1392/03/20' and '1392/03/19'
AND Insure_ID = 0
AND User_ID = 2
GROUP BY insure_id, InsureTitle, status
```

Also, integer columns do not require single quote to surround the values.

Answer (score 0):

You should have to replace your , with and operator and select only those records which you are including in group or MIN , MAX , AVG etc for other columns.

```
SELECT insure_id, InsureTitle, status FROM View_FirstReport
 WHERE Date BETWEEN '1392/03/20' and '1392/03/19'
 AND Insure_ID = 0
 AND User_ID = 2
GROUP BY insure_id, InsureTitle, status
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
SELECT insure_id
    ,InsureTitle
    ,[STATUS]
FROM View_FirstReport
WHERE [DATE] BETWEEN '13920320'
        AND '13920319'
    AND Insure_ID = '0'
    AND [User_ID] = '2'
GROUP BY insure_id
    ,InsureTitle
    ,[STATUS]
```

This is almost similar to SandeepKumar answer.